# How to change the CSS in one file?

Tags: css

Should I go to many files to change the appearance of Wordpress? Isn't it possible to change it form one file?

And what should I learn from CSS to be able to modify Wordpress easily? I mean should I reach to an advanced level?

Comment: Please explain your question. What are you trying to change? admin panel, default theme? Wordpress doesn't require you to learn CSS, that's what wordpress [themes](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/) are for

Answer (score 0):

This completely depends on your skill-level and what theme you're using. Let's take the [Twenty Eleven Theme](http://twentyelevendemo.wordpress.com/) for example (default in current WP version).

If you look at the source of the homepage, you'll see the body element has the following:

```
<body class="home blog two-column right-sidebar highlander-enabled highlander-light infinite-scroll">
```

That is a bunch of classes that you can use to individually style top-level elements. For example, if you wanted post titles only on the homepage to be larger, you could do something like:

```
.home.blog article .entry-title { font-size:100px; }
```

As mentioned, CSS knowledge is needed, but relatively small changes can be done by a web developer pretty quickly.

If your question is "how do I make these changes", these would be typically defined in `styles.css` within your theme, but it is advisable to [Create a Child Theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#Example_of_a_basic_Child_Theme) so you are not editing core WordPress files. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In one aspect it's better to set all stylesheets in only **one** file. This ensures that you're doing as less as possible HTTP requests while loading the page.

The other aspect is the overall view... If you only use one file for your stylesheets it's hard to read and find code in this large file with e.g. 3000 lines of code.

```
Ctrl+F is your friend in big files! ;)
```

> And what should I learn from CSS to be able to modify Wordpress easily? I mean should I reach to an advanced level?

That depends on your needs... I think you don't need much experience to style a blog basicly. If you want more than just some other font sizes and a background image or having trouble with browser compatibility you have to rely on the results of google.

Best regards!